# Detect software installed from website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, windows, google-chrome

I am creating a website in HTML. Is there anyway to detect the software installed on PC where the website is accessed. I am sure it is done by JavaScript but I would not find any guide for it. Also I played around with some jquery and it did not work. Thank you

Comment: `Is there anyway to detect the software installed on PC`  No,  the best you can do is get the `user-agent` string, but that can be faked.

Comment: What ***exactly*** are you trying to detect.  Don't be broad.  You mentioned in a comment how Java can detect gamepads.  JavaScript has this capability too, but the browser is picky (thankfully) about it will and will not disclose.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @zero298 Not anything specific I was just playing with JavaScript and HTML. Can you please elaborate how JavaScript can detect gamepads. I have been searching for a while. Or maybe it can detect drivers and not softwares ? Any thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

No.

JavaScript in browsers is highly [sand-boxed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(computer_security)) for security purposes. There is no way to find out anything about the computer a website is running on other than a very limited subset of information which the browser makes available.

Installed software is not one included in that information, nor are files on the computer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I remember correctly a while ago I used to play an online flash game where it used to detect my virtual controller software. So was it done by flash or JavaScript?

Comment: Flash is able to do more. Flash is not JavaScript. It runs via a plugin installed in the browser which can bypass the sandbox. Flash has largely died out on browsers though precisely because it created some rather major security issues constantly.

Comment: In case of JavaScript is it same for softwares and drivers (I meant are they both hidden from JavaScript or just the softwares list is restricted and drivers are available to access).

Comment: Drivers, file system, software, etc. are all restricted. Just about everything about the computer short of a few very basic things (OS, browser user agent) are hidden. There are some things that have APIs available to them that the browser will make available in a controlled fashion after getting explicit permission from the user (camera, location data, mics, etc.), but that's a very specific list. If there is something specific you care about, I could point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Electron](https://electronjs.org/), and that would allow you to interact with the user through JavaScript (using Node JS).

It requires the user to install your code as an application, however.  So it would no longer be a "website".

Comment: If they are looking to write an application using the web-tech stack, this would be a good solution. I've done similar using Chromium. Though, as you said, this definitely wouldn't count as a website anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: **NO**.  However, I want to answer this carefully and specifically because I think you may be misunderstanding what a browser's goal and capabilities are.  Some facets of your machine are exposed by your browser.  However, some things are intentionally obfuscated to protect end users.

When you are making a web application, you shouldn't be thinking "What does the user have installed that I can leverage".  You should instead try to provide a feature set, and then [progressively enhance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) the user experience based on what a user can and does allow you to make use of.

You commented about how Flash was able to detect gamepads,

> I remember correctly a while ago I used to play an online flash game
>   where it used to detect my virtual controller software. So was it done
>   by flash or JavaScript?

JavaScript can actually do this as well using the [Gamepad API](https://www.w3.org/TR/gamepad/).  See [Using the Gamepad API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Gamepad_API/Using_the_Gamepad_API) for examples.

The thing to note is that the browser is the gatekeeper on this information, and it tries to limit (or it should) what is exposed as much as possible.  For example, another way the browser can betray information is through the [user agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) string which is sent with every request your browser makes.  It can identify what browser you are using as well as what operating system you are using.  Of course it could also be omitted, or flat out lying.

Another thing that can be betrayed is screen resolution.  Since, I would say, users typically run browsers at a maximized resolution, you can glean the dimensions of a users monitor.

You can also get information about whether or not a user has a microphone or a camera with [MediaDevices.getUserMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia).

You can even try to figure out what capabilities a user's GPU has with a WebGL context and asking for debug parameters:

```js
function printContextInfo(gl) {
  console.groupCollapsed("WebGL Information");
  console.groupCollapsed("Version Information");
  console.log(`Version: ${gl.getParameter(gl.VERSION)}`);
  console.log(`Shading Language Version: ${gl.getParameter(gl.SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION)}`);
  console.log(`Renderer: ${gl.getParameter(gl.RENDERER)}`);
  console.groupEnd();
  console.groupCollapsed("Parameter Limits");
  console.log(`Max Texture Size: ${gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE)}`);
  console.log(`Max Viewport Dims: ${gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS)}`);
  console.log(`Max Vertex Attribs: ${gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS)}`);
  console.log(`Max Vertex Uniform Vectors: ${gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS)}`);
  console.log(`Max Varying Vectors: ${gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_VARYING_VECTORS)}`);
  console.log(`Max Combined Texture Image Units: ${gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS)}`);
  console.log(`Max Vertex Texture Image Units: ${gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS)}`);
  console.log(`Max Texture Image Units: ${gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS)}`);
  console.log(`Max Fragment Uniform Vetors: ${gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_VECTORS)}`);
  console.groupEnd();
  console.groupCollapsed("Supported Extensions");
  gl.getSupportedExtensions().forEach(extension => console.log(extension));
  console.groupEnd();
  let debugInfo = gl.getExtension("WEBGL_debug_renderer_info");
  if (debugInfo) {
    console.groupCollapsed("Debug Info");
    console.log(`Unmasked Vendor: ${gl.getParameter(debugInfo.UNMASKED_VENDOR_WEBGL)}`);
    console.log(`Unmasked Renderer: ${gl.getParameter(debugInfo.UNMASKED_RENDERER_WEBGL)}`);
    console.groupEnd();
  }
  console.groupEnd();
}

const canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0],
  ctx = canvas.getContext("webgl");

printContextInfo(ctx);
```

```html
<canvas width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you for the  answer. The reason I wanted to do that was to suggest user similar things he may like, for example if he has some game installed ( say skyrim) the website will suggest similar  games (witcher 3).